# Render login action only if the format html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been doing project on rails and I am very new to it. I want to redirect the user when the user is not logged in but at the same time if the request is in json the app would verify it through api key. So,is there a way to bypass the before_filter if the request is json but not if the format is html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_filter :my_method unless request.xhr?
```